# Execute script in copyright block?

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript, backend, copyright

For some reason, the little script we used to get the current year in the copyright block under `Content/design/configuration/footer` is not being executed. It is being treated as normal text in the frontend

**Backoffice:**

[image: back-office]

**Frontend:**

[image: frontend]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not a bug. It's a feature.**

In the template `html/footer.phtml` from the `Magento_Theme` module there is this:

```
<address><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCopyright()) ?></address>
```

`getCopyright` returns exactly what you have in your config field.
This means that the value is escaped before printing it on the screen.
If you don't want this escape, you can override the template in your theme and replace the code above with

```
<address><?= $block->getCopyright(); ?></address>
```

But this will leave you exposed to XSS if someone inserts some (harmful) javascript code in your copyright section.